# Dependence of kinetic friction on relative velocity

Tags: energy, friction, kinetic-theory

While I was reading my book I came across a line that tells that there is slight dependence of kinetic friction on velocity of relative motion of the bodies.

Can anyone tell me how is this so?

Comment: In  different regimes you might approximate the dependency by some power law, e.eg., proportional to $v$ or $v^2$, but in general there is no simple mathematical function you can write down that will represent the exact dependency.

Comment: Can you then tell me the logical reason for the dependence of velocity?

Comment: Well, for starters do you understand why it shouldn't really depend upon relative position (like gravity)? If so then velocity is the next obvious candidate.